# Chrome Extension: could not unzip extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I made some chrome extensions in WSL.
On Windows Chrome, they are valid with `Load unpacked` but error occured in installing from Chrome Store:
`could not unzip extension`.

I guess that invalid names on Windows and WSL have something with this error.

Chrome Store URL: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hackmd-toc-always/ndljpnnkjlilcglbiabboadbjcncihfb

GitHub Repository: https://github.com/TomoTom0/HackMD_TOC_always

---

Notes:
I can add common chrome extensions but can't add other extensions I made.

---

contents in the directory

```sh
#la *
content_script.js  jquery-3.5.1.min.js  manifest.json  options.html  options_script.js

img:
chrome_reader_mode_black_128dp.png  north_black_48dp.png  unfold_less_black_48dp.png
chrome_reader_mode_black_48dp.png   south_black_48dp.png  unfold_more_black_48dp.png
```

Comment: Your extension has a file with `:` which is an invalid name in Windows. The fact the the web store allowed you to publish such an extension is a bug in itself.

Comment: @wOxxOm I edit question and add the file names. There may be no invalid names....

Comment: There is: `img/icon_128dp.png:Zone.Identifier`

Comment: You can use a proper file manager (not the built-in in MacOS) or https://robwu.nl/crxviewer/

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks!! That works!!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `zip src.zip src -r -x ".* *Zone.Identifier"` works.
SP Thanks to wOxxOm